# How do i find $5 \times 5$ matrix, which has exactly defined eigenvalues and geometric multiplicities?

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I find a $5 \times 5$ matrix, which has exactly the eigenvalues $\lambda _1=3$ and $\lambda _2 = 4$ with the following geometric multiplicities $ g_1 = 3, g_2 = 1$?

Comment: What field is this matrix over?

Comment: I don't understand your question @IrregularUser

Comment: Where do the entries of the matrix live? In $\mathbb{R}$ for example? Or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: It's not written in my example but I think in R

Comment: Do you know how to make a $2 \times 2$ matrix with the eigenvalue $4$ with geometric multiplicity $1$ and no other eigenvalues? Do you know how to make a $3 \times 3$ matrix with the eigenvalue $3$ with geometric multiplicity $3$? If so, put those together in a block-diagonal $5 \times 5$ matrix. If not, reply and we can talk about how to do those.

Comment: @Ian This is what I was stuck on myself, how do we construct a $2 \times 2$ matrix with just eigenvalue $4$ with multiplicity $1$?

Comment: @lan i know that eigenvalues need to be in diagonal but i don't know where to put geomtric multiplicity

Comment: @jebiovo Reducing the problem as I suggested, if you put $4$ on the diagonal twice and nothing else, you get multiplicity $2$. Putting in a single nonzero off-diagonal entry (and leaving the other one alone) lowers the geometric multiplicity to $1$ without changing the eigenvalues (why?)

Comment: @Ian Doesn't $\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 1 \\ 
0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}$ still have eigenvalue $4$ with multiplicity $2$?

Comment: @IrregularUser It doesn't have two independent eigenvectors with $\lambda=4$, so there is no degeneracy. The [defective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defective_matrix) $n\times n$ matrix lacks $n$ eigenvectors unless we generalize what it means to be an eigenvector.

Comment: @zahbaz But it has $\lambda = 4$ repeated, so doesn't it have multiplicity $2$?

Comment: @IrregularUser It has algebraic multiplicity $2$ and *geometric* multiplicity $1$, because $A-4I$ is not just the zero matrix, so it has nonzero rank.

Comment: @Ian Ah! Completely missed that out, thanks.